# why is this test failing on node.js with should and mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, should.js

```
'use strict';

var should = require('should');

describe('wtf', function () {
    it('compare arrays', function (done) {
        [].should.equal([]);
    });
});
```

My tests were working fine until I switched from node 10.26 installed from brew to nvm installed version of 10.33.

Here is the error:

```
AssertionError: expected [] to equal []
Expected :[]
Actual   :[]
```

Comment: [`Assertion#equal` function](http://shouldjs.github.io/#assertion-equal) performs simple equality check with `===` operator. But [you can't compare arrays using `===` operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript). So, you should use deep comparison instead (see **Urahara**'s answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **`should(  [actual]  ).eql( [comapre]  )`** - *deep comparsion*

---

**This will pass**

```
it('compare arrays', function (done) {
    var test = [];
    should(test).eql([]);
    done();
});
```

---

**This will fail**

```
it('compare arrays', function (done) {
    var test = ['t'];
    should(test).eql([]);
    done();
});
```

---

> Note: Remember to finish the `async` tests with `done()`

Comment: That was it. thank you! -- i figured it had something to do with that but couldn't find the docs.